# Matrix Class Mem Allocating & Overloading

Tags: c++, class, matrix, heap-memory

I want to dynamically allocate memory for the matrix, in the constructor. I want `mData` to be a pointer to `double` values.

`getvalue() setValue()` the getter should return the value at row_x and column_x, and the setter should set the value at row_x and column_x, but getter and setter doesn't seem to work;

`operator +` have to  check for 2 same sized matrix, and summing element by element.

`Operator *` also needs to check for 2 same sized matrix, and multiply element by element.

`Operator ^` needs to check if it is possible to multiply row by column 2 matrix, and then do that.

Here is my code:

```
class Mat {
private:
    uint16_t mRows;
    uint16_t mCols;
    double * mData;
public:
    Mat(uint16_t r, uint16_t c){
        mRows = r;
        mCols = c;
        mData = new double[mRows * mCols];
    }
    Mat(uint16_t c){
        mCols = c;
        mRows = 1;
        mData = new double [mCols];
    }
    Mat(){
        mRows = 0;
        mCols = 0;
    }
    Mat(const Mat &mat) : mRows(mat.mRows), mCols(mat.mCols), mData(mat.mData){

    }
    double getValue(uint16_t r, uint16_t c){

        double val = mData [r*c + c];
        return val;
    }
    void setValue(uint16_t r, uint16_t c,double value){
        mData[r*c + c] = value;
    }
    ~Mat(){
        
    }
    Mat operator + (const Mat &mat){
        Mat result;
        int ok=0;
        if(mat.mRows == mRows && mat.mCols == mCols){
            ok=1;
            result.mData[mRows*mCols ] = mData[mRows*mCols ] + mat.mData[mat.mRows*mat.mCols];
        }
        if(ok == 0)
           return result.mData[0];
        else
            return result;
    }
    Mat operator * (const Mat &mat){
        Mat result;
        int ok=0;
        if(mat.mRows == mRows && mat.mCols == mCols){
            ok=1;
            result.mData[mRows*mCols] = mData[mRows*mCols] * mat.mData[mat.mRows*mat.mCols];
        }
        if(ok == 0)
            return result.mData[0];
        else
            return result.mData[mRows*mCols];
    }
     Mat operator ^ (const Mat &mat){
        Mat result;
        int ok=0;
        if(mat.mRows == mCols && mat.mCols == mRows){
            ok=1;
            result.mData[mRows] = mData[mRows] * mat.mData[mat.mCols];
        }
        if(ok == 0)
            return result.mData[0];
        else
            return result.mData[mRows];
    }


};
```

I want to continue with this idea, but i am not sure what i am missing

Comment: Note that it should be `mData[r*mCols+c]` instead of `r*c+c`.

Comment: @MarcStevens Thanks, now the getter and setter work well. But how can i correctly complete the operators + * and ^ ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can simplify your own memory management by changing mData to a std::vector<double>. Then operator +, *, ^ can simply iterate over the vectors elements: `for (size_t i = 0; i < result.mData.size(); ++i) result.mData[i] = src1.mData[i] + src2.mData[i];`. We can simplify the double loop over first rows and then columns to a single loop over all elements, since all matrix elements are contiguous in memory.

Comment: It's not clear what you want with the operator ^, do you mean regular matrix matrix multiplication, where m x n matrix is multiplied with an n x k matrix and results in an m x k matrix? Instead of simply element wise.

Answer (score 2):

Using `std::vector<double>` instead of `double*` makes the memory management and copying significant easier and less error prone.
I've also noticed an error in element wise access, where one should use `r*mCols+c` instead of `r*c+c`. To solve the problem with element wise matrix operations, you need to walk over all elements:

```
for (size_t r = 0; r < mRows; ++r)
   for (size_t c = 0; c < mCols; ++c)
      result[r*mCols+c] = src1[r*mCols+c] + src2[r*mCols+c]
```

Here is an example implementation of Mat. I've only done `operator+` so far, but should easily extend to the other operators:

```
class Mat
{
private:
    size_t mRows;
    size_t mCols;
    std::vector<double> mData;
public:
    // constructors
    Mat(size_t rows, size_t cols, double v = 0.0f)
        : mRows(rows), mCols(cols), mData(mRows*mCols, v)
    {}
    Mat(size_t cols, double v = 0.0f)
        : mRows(1), mCols(cols), mData(mRows*mCols,v)
    {}
    Mat()
        : mRows(0), mCols(0), mData()
    {} 

    // automatic copy & move construction just works^TM using std::vector
    Mat(const Mat&) = default;
    Mat(Mat&&) = default;
    // same with automatic copy & move assignment
    Mat& operator= (const Mat&) = default;
    Mat& operator= (Mat&&) = default;

    // element access
    double getValue(size_t r, size_t c) const
    {
        return mData[r*mCols + c];
    }
    void setValue(size_t r, size_t c, double value)
    {
        mData[r*mCols + c] = value;
    }

    // element access through operator():
    // Mat m(3,3); m(1,2)=5.0f;
    double& operator()(size_t r, size_t c)
    {
        return mData[r*mCols + c];
    }
    const double& operator()(size_t r, size_t c) const
    {
        return mData[r*mCols + c];
    }

    // in place addition saves unnecessary memory allocation & copying
    Mat& operator += (const Mat& m)
    {
        if (m.mRows != mRows || m.mCols != mCols)
            throw std::runtime_error("Mat: dimensions don't match");
        // since all matrix elements are contiguous in memory, we can simply to a single for loop
        for (size_t i = 0; i < mData.size(); ++i)
            mData[i] += m.mData[i];
        return *this;
    }

    
    Mat operator + (const Mat& m) const
    {
        if (m.mRows != mRows || m.mCols != mCols)
            throw std::runtime_error("Mat: dimensions don't match");
        // copy this Mat into a new Mat
        Mat result(*this);
        // add m to result in place and return result
        result += m;
        return result;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your memory management is broken.

In your copy constructor, you have to copy the contents of `mData`, not just the pointer. So you need to allocate a new buffer and copy the input data to that.

Your destructor needs to delete `mData`, you are leaking memory.

In your operators, you can't use a *default constructed* matrix as the target. You have to create your target with the correct dimensions or it doesn't have a buffer allocated!

The return values of your operators are illegal. You must always return the type specified in the signature. You must not return `result.mData[0]`, not even in the error case! You can either return a default constructed `Mat` or `throw` an exception in such case.